# Searching for substring inbetween character and whitespace

Tags: python

I'm trying to search for a string inbetween a whitespace and `§7:`. I've tried:

```
re.search(r' (.*?)§7:', line1)
```

and

```
re.search(r'\s*(.*?)§7:', line1)
```

Along with a few other things I've found from other posts but can't seem to figure it out. I can't search for a different character because the strings I'm searching for change and sometimes will have different characters at the beginning but will always have a space.

```
User§r INEEDTHIS§7: message
User§b] b] INEEDTHIS§f: message
```

Comment: And? What is the problem? Your first regex [seems to work](https://regex101.com/r/wKll9y/1)...

Answer (score 0):

From what i gathered from your code, your are searching each line individually,
so this regex should work:

```
re.findall(r'\s(.*?)\§7')
```

the difference is that I used findAll, so you can just call it on the entire text file

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex seems to be correct. You just need to get the first capturing group like this:

```py
re.search(r" (.*?)§7:", line1).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

your first regex looks ok.

if you want to get all the results you should use `re.findall`:

```
re.findall(r" (.*?)§7:", line1)
```

if you want the first result use `re.search`:

```
re.search(r" (.*?)§7:", line1).group(1)
```